# Ruby: Adding different array values into hash for the same key

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to add different values into an array for the same key into the hash. Instead of making a new instance in the array, my function sum ups the index values of the array elements

```
def dupe_indices(array)
    hash = Hash.new([])
    array.each.with_index { |ele, idx| hash[ele] = (idx) }
    hash
end
```

I'm getting this

```
print dupe_indices(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']) => {"a"=>3, "b"=>1, 
"c"=>4}
```

Expected output

```
print dupe_indices(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']) => { 'a' => [0, 3], 'b' 
=> [1], 'c' => [2, 4] }
```

Comment: Alternatively `ary.each_index.group_by { |i| ary[i] }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With two small modifications your code willl work.

1. change `hash = Hash.new([])` to `hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }`

you should really never use `Hash.new([])`, see this article for an explanation: https://mensfeld.pl/2016/09/ruby-hash-default-value-be-cautious-when-you-use-it/

2. Change `hash[ele] = (idx)` to `hash[ele].push(idx)`

you don't want to *replace* the value whenever you encounter a new index, you want to *push it to the array*.

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']

def dupe_indices(array)
    hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
    array.each.with_index { |ele, idx| hash[ele].push(idx) }
    hash
end

dupe_indices(array)
# => {"a"=>[0, 3], "b"=>[1], "c"=>[2, 4]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm a little bit confused with this line: hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }, particulary with 'h' argument.

Comment: H and k stand for hash and key. When an unknown key gets looked up in the hash, this block is called. You can google for "ruby default hash block" for more explanation, in on the go right now

Comment: Timur, `each.with_index` is generally written `each_with_index` unless one wants the index to have a base other than zero (e.g., `...each.with_index(1)...`). Defining the hash as it is done here is effectively the same as `hash = {};  array.each_with_index { |ele, idx| hash[ele] = [] unless hash.key?(ele); hash[ele].push(idx) }; hash`. Lastly, you could reduce the body of the method to one line by writing  `array.each_with_index.with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(ele, idx), hash| hash[ele].push(idx) }`.

Comment: @TimurShamuradov: "I'm a little bit confused with this line: hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }, particulary with 'h' argument" – It would be helpful if you could describe what *precisely* is unclear to you about the documentation of `Hash::new`. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers do not stumble across the same problems as you. Help make the world a better place!